# mmenu Wordpress Plugin: Can I put it inside a container?

Tags: wordpress, menu, mmenu

I'm developing a website for a client, and he has requested sliding navigation for the sidebar of his site. His menu is built by listing categories, their child categories, *their* child categories, and finally the posts in each.

For the mobile version of the website, mmenu is pretty much a dream come true. However, I'm having trouble translating it for desktop.

There's a specific space that the sidebar should go, which has a specified percentage width, as mmenu does.

Is there any way to move mmenu's "widescreen" version inside of my sidebar div?

Alternately, are there any other plugins that function similarly, but would allow me to do this?

Thanks!

Paige

Comment: are you asking about max mega menu pluggin or?

Comment: @Apeiron : Nope, I'm asking about  a plugin called mmenu (http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/).

Comment: The only way I can think of is adding the mmenu with javascript into the container.